# Access to types declared outside @model scope in MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I have created a PersonList class which contains lists of different groups of peoples. In my controller I will be passing that class to the view. My view is strongly typed so I reference to that class. But my view requires types of that groups (Student, Retired, Politic) so I can use them in conditional statement in View. I solved that problem by adding one object per group in PersonList class but I feel that is not best way to do it. Please direct me to better solution.

> .cs file

```
public interface IPerson
{
}
public abstract class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public Int16 Age { get; set; }
}
public class Politics : Person, IPerson
{
    public string Party { get; set; }
    public int Experience { get; set; }
}
public class Students : Person, IPerson
{
    public string Major { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
}
public class Retired: Person, IPerson
{
    public int Pension { get; set; }
    public string Hobby { get; set; }
}
public class PersonLists : IPerson
{
    public List<Retired> AllRetired = new List<Retired>();
    public List<IPerson> AllPeople = new List<IPerson>();
    public Students AStudent = new Students();
    public Politics APolitic = new Politics();
    public Retired ARetired = new Retired();
}
```

> cshtml file:

```
@model ConferenceAttendees.Models.PersonLists
<style>
h6 {
    display: inline
}
th{
    text-align:center;

}
</style>
<div>
    <table style="width:100%" align="left">
        <tr>
            <th>Imie</th>
            <th>Nazwisko</th>
            <th>Wiek</th>
            <th>Partia</th>
            <th>Doswiadczenie</th>
            <th>Kierunek</th>
            <th>Rok</th>
        </tr>
            @foreach (dynamic item in Model.AllPeople)
            {
              <tr>
              <th>@item.Name</th>
              <th>@item.LastName</th>
              <th>@item.Age</th> 
                @if (item.GetType() == Model.APolitic.GetType())
                {
                    <th>@item.Party</th>
                    <th>@item.Experience</th>
                    <th>b.d</th>
                    <th>b.d</th>
                }
                @if (item.GetType() == Model.AStudent.GetType())
                {
                    <th>b.d</th>
                    <th>b.d</th>
                    <th>@item.Major</th>
                    <th>@item.Year</th>
                }
              </tr>
            }
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Create a custom made view-model and compose that model in the controller. Remove the @if statements from the View

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can import a namespace in your Razor view via the [`@using`](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/views/razor.html#using) directive. You can do this before the `@model` directive. Then, you can use your types `Students` and `Politics` in your view.

Second, to check if `item` is of a concrete type, you can use the [`as`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx) operator and see if the result is not `null`. So, you don't need to call `GetType()` on your instances. Now you can remove your `AStudent`, `APolitic` and `ARetired` instances.

Also, two side notes to your code:

1. Do not use `dynamic` in the `foreach` loop. You don't need dynamic typing here. Instead, use `Person` as type for the `item` variable. For this to work, `AllPeople` must be of type `List<Person>` instead of `List<IPerson>`. In fact, you do not need the `IPerson` interface at all since you don't define anything in there.
2. I suggest not using the plural form for your classes (`Students`, `Politics`). One instance of `Students` is just *one* student, so why not call the class `Student`? Same for `Politics`.

All in all, your view now looks like this:

```
@using ConferenceAttendees.Models
@model ConferenceAttendees.Models.PersonLists
<style>
h6 {
    display: inline
}
th{
    text-align:center;

}
</style>
<div>
    <table style="width:100%" align="left">
        <tr>
            <th>Imie</th>
            <th>Nazwisko</th>
            <th>Wiek</th>
            <th>Partia</th>
            <th>Doswiadczenie</th>
            <th>Kierunek</th>
            <th>Rok</th>
        </tr>
            @foreach (Person item in Model.AllPeople)
            {
              var student = item as Student;
              var politician = item as Politician;
              <tr>
              <th>@item.Name</th>
              <th>@item.LastName</th>
              <th>@item.Age</th> 
                @if (politician != null)
                {
                    <th>@politician.Party</th>
                    <th>@politician.Experience</th>
                    <th>b.d</th>
                    <th>b.d</th>
                }
                @if (student != null)
                {
                    <th>b.d</th>
                    <th>b.d</th>
                    <th>@student.Major</th>
                    <th>@student.Year</th>
                }
              </tr>
            }
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! All you described works fine despite suggestion about dynamic in foreach. When I replace dynamic in foreach by IPerson I get this error: "Cannot convert method group 'Name' to non delegate type 'object'. Did you intended to invoke this method?".

Comment: Sure, this cannot work. My fault. I updated my answer.

Comment: When I did as you suggested I got following error: "Confference.Attendees.Model.Person does not contain definition of 'Party'(...)"

Comment: Oh sorry, in the if-blocks you have to use the `politician` and `student` variables of course. This is what happens when I just edit the answer without checking if that actually compiles... I updated my answer again.